# I dont know how to create the image below using nested for loops (java)

Tags: java, loops

```
|""""""""""|
 \::::::::/
  \::::::/
   \::::/
    \::/
     ||
    /::\
   /::::\
  /::::::\
|""""""""""|
```

How do I use nested loops to create this?

Comment: How have you attempted to do it so far?

Comment: I wasnt sure how to start, I used some println statments but I am Not sure how to create the pattern using the for loops.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the language you're using as a tag to help guide potential answers.

Comment: what is the input?

Comment: java is the langauge

Comment: You really need to make some effort and show us what you have tried. Here is a hint to get you started with the top bit `line = padding + "\" + middle + "/"`, you can use a loop to work out how much padding to add, and how many characters to add to the middle.

Comment: What have you tried so far? One way to see the patterns is to draw the figure on graph paper, and manually count all the characters you need to print.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, consider it as a `12*12` matrix.
First print the required spaces, 0 spaces for row 0, 1 space for row 1...
Now, to print the symbols, you can use two nested `for` loops.

1. Start with the corners first and print `|` if the position is a corner.
2. If it's the first or last row, then print `"`.
3. All the `\` and `/` are present on the diagonal of the matrix so for primary diagonal print `\` and for secondary diagonal print `/`.
4. If it's none of the above, then print the `:`.

Something like the below will print the upper half which can be modified to get the rest of required pattern:

```java
        int N = 12;
        for (int i=0; i<N/2; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
                System.out.print(" ");
            for (int j=0; i+j<=N-1; j++)
            {
                if (i==0&&j==0 || i==N-1&&j==N-1 || i==0&j==N-1 || i==N-1&&j==0)
                    System.out.print("|");
                else if (i==0)
                    System.out.print("\"");
                else if (i==j)
                    System.out.print("\\");
                else if (i+j==N-1)
                    System.out.print("/");
                else if (j >= i)
                    System.out.print(":");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
```